# Double doesn't scan properly

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  double a;
  char b[32];
  scanf("%31[^,] %lf", b, &a);
  printf("%s, %lf", b, a);
  return 0;
}
```

String `b` is stored properly, but variable `a` isn't. What is my error?

Comment: The format `%31[^,]` reads *until* the comma, but doesn't read the comma itself.

Comment: `if (scanf(...) != 2) /* error */;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
scanf("%31[^,] %lf", b, &a);
```

to this:

```
scanf("%31[^,], %lf", b, &a);
```

since the format `%31[^,]` reads *until* the comma, but does *not* read the comma itself, as commented. As a result, you need to add an additional comma.

This also explains why `b` gets populated as expected, because its the first variable to get filled. The issue starts after the comma, which explains why "`a` variable isn't stored properly".

As @pmg commented, you should really check the number of matches, which in your case is two. With your code, you'd have got a non-expected return value from the method, and realized that something is wrong in the format. Example:

```
if (scanf("%31[^,], %lf", b, &a) != 2)
  /* error */;
```